# How to pack std::thread with template constructor and lambda function？

Tags: c++, lambda, rvalue, lvalue, stdthread

Why is data in func() repeated?

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

    struct Data {
    int id;
};

class Thread {
    public:
    template <class Function, class... Args>
    Thread(Function &&f, Args &&...args) noexcept
        : internal_{ [func = std::forward<Function>(f), &args...]() {
            func(args...);
        } }
    {
    }

    private:
    std::thread internal_;
};

void func(Data *data)
{
    printf("                in thread, data: %p, id: %d\n", data, data->id);
}

int main()
{
    static Data data[8];
    std::vector<Thread *> threads;
    volatile int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        data[i].id = i;
        printf("out thread, data: %p\n", &data[i]);
        auto tmp = new Thread(func, &data[i]);
        threads.emplace_back(tmp);
    }

    sleep(100);
    return 0;
}
```

```
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d040
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d044
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d044, id: 1
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d048
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d048, id: 2
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d04c
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d04c, id: 3
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d050
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d04c, id: 3
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d054
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d054, id: 5
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d058
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d054, id: 5
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d058, id: 6
out thread, data: 0x562bb497d05c
                in thread, data: 0x562bb497d05c, id: 7
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them. Like including all the details in the question body itself, while keeping the title a short summary.

Comment: Aside: why not `internal_{std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...}`? Or even omit the `Thread` class entirely, and have a `std::vector<std::thread>`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Thread(Function &&f, Args &&...args) noexcept
    : internal_{ [func = std::forward<Function>(f), &args...]() {
        func(args...);  // _________________________^_______
    } }
{
}
```

You dump the local parameter/variable `&args` captured by reference. This is a reference to a destroyed object, undefined behavior. Remove `&` to capture the variable by value and you will get proper addresses of `data[i]`.

Comment: Thanks very much. But I want to kown what's the error of the code I pasted.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Regardless of this, your code has a couple of other serious errors.

Comment: `This is a reference to a destroyed object` Which object be destroyed ? They are all reference!

What I mean is: Args &&...args and &args ... are all reference，and I pass the address when I new Thread(). There should print 8 different value in func().

Comment: `Args&& args` deduces to `Data* args`. `args` is a local variable in the constructor. If you want to pass a reference, pass a reference instead of forwarding reference. Want you me to update the answer with a reference `args`?

Comment: If args in Thread(Function &&f, Args &&...args) is local and has been destroyed. Please see below code，the id printed in func() is al right. I think, if the data in Thread(Function &&f, Data && data) has been destroyed， the id printed in func() is unpredictable.

Comment: The printed `id` are not correct: 3 3 5 5. This is undefined behavior, it may sometimes look like to behave correctly.

Comment: ```#include <unistd.h>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Data {
  int id;
};

class Thread {
 public:
  template <class Function, class... Args>
  Thread(Function &&f, Data && data) noexcept
          : internal_{[func = std::forward<Function>(f), &data]() {
          func(data);
        }} {}

 private:
  std::thread internal_;
};

void func(Data data) {
  printf("                            in thread, id: %d\n", data.id);
}```

Comment: ```int main() {
  Data data[8];
  std::vector<Thread *> threads;
  volatile int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    data[i].id = i;
    printf("out thread, data: %p, id: %d\n", &data[i], data[i].id);
    auto tmp = new Thread(func, std::move(data[i]));
    threads.emplace_back(tmp);
  }

  sleep(100);
  return 0;
}```

Comment: Code above, I pass data[i]， the id printed in func() is always right.  I think, if the data in Thread(Function &&f, Data && data) has been destroyed，the id printed in func() will also be unpredictable.

Comment: This is **undefined behavior**. I got 0 0 and no 7.

Comment: Really ?  I expand the thread num from 8 to 16 and test more than 20 times. There is no error. I run it in virtual machine ubantu 20.04. Could you give me a screenshot  about the error to 18310430899@163.com.  Thanks very much.

Comment: Enjoy it https://godbolt.org/z/9K4YeWx9c The new run gave me four 0.

Comment: undefined behaviour **is allowed** to masquerade as "works for me"